# Twitter kit for android : Show reply, favorite and retweet options in embedded tweets

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using fabric android sdk to show the user timeline in our app by using TweetViewFetchAdapter as specified in this doc:

```
[Twitter timeline]
```

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/tweetui

[Twitter feeds]

[image]

But it doesn't show options like reply, favorite, retweet etc. Is there any way to provide these options by using TweetUi Kit? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom style to with following line of code with **tw__tweet_actions_enabled** as true in your styles.xml and use your custom style in your TweetTimelineListAdapter class object with following method :

setViewStyle(R.style.custom_tweet_style)